# How to modify SurveyJS page property after timeout (minimum time)?

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

I'm trying to set minimum time for a question in a SurveyJS survey. I want the navigation buttons to appear only after a certain time (3 seconds in the example). Yet when I try to modify `navigationButtonsVisibility` using JS's `setTimeout()` it doesn't work.

```js
const showNavigation = function () {
  console.log("show navigation"); // debug
  survey.currentPage.navigationButtonsVisibility = "show";
};

survey.onCurrentPageChanged.add((sender, options) => {
  setTimeout(showNavigation, 3000);
});
```

The `showNavigation()` function runs but the buttons do not appear. It works outside `setTimeout()` so it could be a scoping problem. I use React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it according to [this](https://surveyjs.answerdesk.io/ticket/details/t10098/add-and-remove-buttons-dynamically-in-navigation-does-not-work-anymore) question.

```js
survey.onCurrentPageChanged.add((sender, options) => {
    let nextButton = survey.navigationBar.getActionById("sv-nav-next");
    nextButton.visible = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
      nextButton.visible = true;
    }, 3000);
});
```